# Secondary Model not inserting data larave multiple model on same table

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 projects (Project A and Project B) both are using the same database and it has a table called `items` which is primarily created from Project A . and From Project A it is connected to a model called Item.php and all the things in project A are working fine .

In Project B I have a model called Product and it is also using the items table .
I have put protected $table = 'items'; there .
In Project B I can get all the data which are created from Project B and manupulate accordingly .
But when I try to create items from Project B it gives me error : `Undefined Index:id,` but it populates the data in the database but I cant get data that in project B .

Important: But when I use DB facade to insert and get data it  gives me no error and it is working fine .

But if I try to insert data using mass assignment or by created object instance like `$product = new Product` it does not work any clue what is happening .

Comment: can you show the model from Project B, and what you are doing that causes the `Undefined index` error?

Comment: How you differentiate Project A and Project B in your table?